# Square Bullet Points on Safari?

Tags: html, css, unicode

For a project I need a row of square dots

---

[image: Row of dots]

---

This is a cropped image rendered in Chrome. This is the code:

```
<ul class="horizontal-status">
    <li class="status-selected">▪</li>
    <li>▪</li>
    <li>▪</li>
    <li>▪</li>
    <li>▪</li>
</ul>
```

This is exactly what I want, but in Safari it looks like this:

---

[image]

---

I want get it to look how it does on Chrome on Safari. I've done some research and some people say to use a font with that square bullet point (doable), but I'm already using a bunch of images and other resources and I can't add any more time to the loading speed. I've tried doing the `display: inline;` on the `ul` but it just removes the bullet points. That's why I added the square symbols. I'd also like it to be square bullet points and not round bullet points. Is there some unicode character that is universal? I'm also using a vertical row of square dots, so I'd like to be able to get the same character/size on both rows so they look the same. Any ideas or suggestions are greatly appreciated.

Comment: Did you set the correct [`charset`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/meta#attr-charset)? In which version of Safari does this fail? It looks fine in Safari on iOS.

Comment: @insertusernamehere I didn't use any but when I used the the `UTF-8` it gave be the emjoi block, so I couldn't change the color. `UTF-8` was the best working one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The **[list-style-type](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/list-style-type)** CSS property (`style="list-style-type:square"`) is supported in all major browsers, including Safari:

```html
<ul style="list-style-type:square">
  <li>Item</li>
  <li>Item</li>
  <li>Item</li>
  <li>Item</li>
</ul>
```

To display the list horizontally, you can add `float: left` to `<li>. Note that you'll also want`margin-left` to prevent the elements from stacking on top of one another. This can be seen in the following:

```css
li {
    float: left;
    margin-left: 25px;
}
```

```html
<ul style="list-style-type:square">
  <li>Item</li>
  <li>Item</li>
  <li>Item</li>
  <li>Item</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: @Obsidian_Age Could you give and example of this in a horizontal list? It seems to remove the bullet points as I stated in my anser. Thanks for the quick response.

Comment: You can apply `float: left` in conjunction with `margin-left` on `<li>` to have them display horizontally, which retains the square bullet point. I'm not quite sure how your custom CSS rules are turning your bullet points into a horizontal display, but they will stack with a simple `float`. You likely need `margin` as well. I've updated my answer to show this working horizontally :)

Answer (score 0):

You can create the squares using pure CSS :

```css
.horizontal-status,
.vertical-status{
  list-style: none;
}

.horizontal-status li {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0 4px;
  width: 5px;
  height: 5px;
  background: blue;
}

.horizontal-status li.status-selected,
.vertical-status li.status-selected{
  background: red;
}

.vertical-status li {
  display: block;
  margin: 10px 0;
  width: 5px;
  height: 5px;
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<ul class="horizontal-status">
  <li class="status-selected"></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
</ul>

<ul class="vertical-status">
  <li class="status-selected"></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for all the answers. Insertusernamehere's comment really helped. I wasn't using a `<meta>` tag to define my `charset`. I then used this meta tag

```
<meta charset="UTF-8">
```

This gave me an black square emoji on Safari but a quick google search told be to add `&#xFE0E;` to the end of the block so my new working code was

```css
.horizontal-status li {
  display: inline;
}
```

```html
<ul class="horizontal-status">
      <li class="status-selected">▪&#xFE0E;</li>
      <li>▪&#xFE0E;</li>
      <li>▪&#xFE0E;</li>
      <li>▪&#xFE0E;</li>
      <li>▪&#xFE0E;</li>
  </ul>
```

Hope this helps